# Is using a step function to limit the value of a function considered inelegant?

Tags: functions

I am a programmer and recently we had some problems with a certain function $f$ that tends to infinity near 10, and we can not have such great values as a result.

Recently there was a collegue trying to tweak the original function to get it close to a fixed number, suppose 10. Although I just suggested using a step function (programming if) to solve it quickly, he said that it could be seen as sloppy or lazy.

Considering that neither of us are mathematicians nor math gurus, is this approach considered negatively by mathematicians?

Edit: Thanks a lot for your responses and sadly I do not recall the exact function, and my collegue is absent, although as soon as he is back I will ask him the formula.

Comment: Why would you possibly care?!

Comment: You will probably get better information if you describe the function (and its purpose) along with the two different adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You know we all became mathematicians for the same reason: we were lazy."

-- Max Rosenlicht

Comment: I was just about to write a comment in that direction, like using multiplication to count oranges stacked in a pyramid instead of counting them, and in general trying to avoid doin the same over and over again, when I noted your answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah: how could anyone get the impression that mathematicians aren't interested in time saving devices?! The OP might be suffering from that widespread delusion that *math is supposed to make things difficult.*

Comment: @rschwieb thanks and I hope that I can dialogue with my collegue into doing the simplest solution and not having to deal with problems that can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematicians do this sort of "tweaking" all the time.  It is not inherently "sloppy or lazy".  Of course I don't know anything about your particular problem - there may or may not be better approaches.